# joomla menu item link to article does not link to the article

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-template

I have linked my joomla menu item to the article by selecting the article in the menu item. 
IT does not pull up the article.

I can create a html module and add content to the page.

i have feeling it could be the template

Comment: You need to provide more information, eg. what does it pull up... what template (is it a commercial one?) do you have a link showing the problem?

Comment: Voted to close as off-topic (this is not a programming question). Please support the [Joomla proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/34294/joomla-answers) on area51 if you'd like a dedicated Joomla equivalent of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the article, menu module, and menu item are all published.